# SQL Select First, Second, Third, Fourth ,Last

Tags: sql, database, select, group-by

I have a membership database with number people living in the same address. To minimise the postal expenditure when mailing newsletters, I would like to select unique addresses from the database and add all the names on the same label sticker of people who live at the same address. Fields I have in the `Members` table are `Names`, `AddressLine1`, `AddressLine2`, `Suburb`, `State`, `Postcode`.

I'm happy to create a new table with for example additional fields called `FirstOfName`, `SecondOfNames`, `ThirdOfNames`, `LastOfNames` if required. The maximum number of people living in the same address in my database is 5.

Example of required output on a label:

```
John Smith

Jane Smith

10 High Street

Beverly Hills, NSW 2000
```

Any help is much appreciated as I'm having much difficulties with this one.

Thanks heaps,
Mika

Answer (score 0):

I assume your ideal objective is to get up to five names and one address in a single complex query.  This example is in PostgreSQL.  You did not specify the database but I believe that corollaries exist in ORACLE and SQLServer.  You will have to make your own adaptations.

Its a little messy but it works.  In short you use WINDOW function to rank the multiple names per unique address.  Use the WITH clause to isolate each name by rank.  LEFT JOIN to select names for addresses with fewer than five names.

Sample table:

```
   DROP TABLE name_address;

   CREATE TABLE name_address
   (
   first_name CHARACTER VARYING (50)
   ,last_name CHARACTER VARYING (50)
   ,addr_line1 CHARACTER VARYING (50)
   ,city CHARACTER VARYING (50)
   ,state CHARACTER VARYING (2)
   ,zip  CHARACTER VARYING (5)
   )
   WITH (OIDS=TRUE);
   ALTER TABLE name_address OWNER TO your_name_here;
```

Sample data:

```
   INSERT INTO name_address (first_name, last_name, addr_line1, city, state, zip) SELECT 'John', 'Smith', '10 High Street', 'Beverly Hills NSW 2000', 'CA', '90210';
   INSERT INTO name_address (first_name, last_name, addr_line1, city, state, zip) SELECT 'Jane', 'Smith', '10 High Street', 'Beverly Hills NSW 2000', 'CA', '90210';
   INSERT INTO name_address (first_name, last_name, addr_line1, city, state, zip) SELECT 'Jeff', 'Smith', '12 High Street', 'Beverly Hills NSW 2000', 'CA', '90210';
   INSERT INTO name_address (first_name, last_name, addr_line1, city, state, zip) SELECT 'Jean', 'Smith', '12 High Street', 'Beverly Hills NSW 2000', 'CA', '90210';
   INSERT INTO name_address (first_name, last_name, addr_line1, city, state, zip) SELECT 'Jenn', 'Smith', '12 High Street', 'Beverly Hills NSW 2000', 'CA', '90210';
   INSERT INTO name_address (first_name, last_name, addr_line1, city, state, zip) SELECT 'Jack', 'Smith', '12 High Street', 'Beverly Hills NSW 2000', 'CA', '90210';
   INSERT INTO name_address (first_name, last_name, addr_line1, city, state, zip) SELECT 'Josh', 'Smith', '12 High Street', 'Beverly Hills NSW 2000', 'CA', '90210';
```

The solution:

```
   WITH nr AS (SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name, addr_line1, city, state, zip, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY zip, state, city, addr_line1 ORDER BY zip, state, city, addr_line1, last_name, first_name) AS name_rank
   FROM name_address
   GROUP BY first_name, last_name, addr_line1, city, state, zip
   ORDER BY zip, state, city, addr_line1, name_rank)
   ,n1 AS(SELECT nr.first_name, nr.last_name, nr.addr_line1, nr.city, nr.state, nr.zip
   FROM nr
   WHERE nr.name_rank = 1)
   ,n2 AS(SELECT nr.first_name, nr.last_name, nr.addr_line1, nr.city, nr.state, nr.zip
   FROM nr
   WHERE nr.name_rank = 2)
   ,n3 AS(SELECT nr.first_name, nr.last_name, nr.addr_line1, nr.city, nr.state, nr.zip
   FROM nr
   WHERE nr.name_rank = 3)
   ,n4 AS(SELECT nr.first_name, nr.last_name, nr.addr_line1, nr.city, nr.state, nr.zip
   FROM nr
   WHERE nr.name_rank = 4)
   ,n5 AS(SELECT nr.first_name, nr.last_name, nr.addr_line1, nr.city, nr.state, nr.zip
   FROM nr
   WHERE nr.name_rank = 5)
   SELECT   DISTINCT n1.first_name
       , n1.last_name
       , n2.first_name
       , n2.last_name
       , n3.first_name
       , n3.last_name
       , n4.first_name
       , n4.last_name
       , n5.first_name
       , n5.last_name
       , na.addr_line1
       , na.city
       , na.state
       , na.zip
   FROM name_address AS na
   LEFT JOIN n1 ON n1.addr_line1 = na.addr_line1 AND n1.city = na.city AND n1.state = na.state AND n1.zip = na.zip
   LEFT JOIN n2 ON n2.addr_line1 = na.addr_line1 AND n2.city = na.city AND n2.state = na.state AND n2.zip = na.zip
   LEFT JOIN n3 ON n3.addr_line1 = na.addr_line1 AND n3.city = na.city AND n3.state = na.state AND n3.zip = na.zip
   LEFT JOIN n4 ON n4.addr_line1 = na.addr_line1 AND n4.city = na.city AND n4.state = na.state AND n4.zip = na.zip
   LEFT JOIN n5 ON n5.addr_line1 = na.addr_line1 AND n5.city = na.city AND n5.state = na.state AND n5.zip = na.zip;
```

Here's the final output:

"Jane";"Smith";"John";"Smith";"";"";"";"";"";"";"10 High Street";"Beverly Hills NSW 2000";"CA";"90210"
"Jack";"Smith";"Jean";"Smith";"Jeff";"Smith";"Jenn";"Smith";"Josh";"Smith";"12 High Street";"Beverly Hills NSW 2000";"CA";"90210"